# I need some clarification with でも as particles!

Tags: particle-で, particle-も, particle-でも, topic

Here is my question:

I started to learn particles and one of the lessons is that when a location is the topic I can attach は and も to the particles に, へ and で.

I understand most of it, except when I have も attached to で. Could I have an example of how this would be used with location?

And lastly... Is でも as in "but/however" related to these particles or it is a non related word?

Disclaimer: I'm still not good with kanji, so if possible add the kana.

Comment: Share the material you are learning from!

Comment: @JACK I use mostly https://itazuraneko.neocities.org/ and https://www.coscom.co.jp/index.html Other than that, I search everywhere!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

でも meaning even/but/however is the て form of the copula です.　The て form can allow you to do many things, but the most basic use is that it allows you to join to clauses together. You can think of it as meaning "and." も is the inclusionary particle which you use when you want to say "also" or "in addition too."

An example of でも would be 先生でも間違{まちが｝います。Even a teacher makes mistakes.

You could use でも to state where an event took place as well. Do recall that も is the inclusionary particle though and you must use it when you are talking about similar topics.

If a topic of the activity "having fun" were already introduced at a certain location then you could state that you also "had fun" at another place.

プールでは遊｛あそ}んだ。 X had fun in/at the pool.　（Topic is introduced by は, verb is playing)

ジョンの家{いえ}でも遊｛あそ}んだ。 X ALSO had fun in/at John's house. (Topic, which is another location, is marked by も, verb is playing)

If you did something other than "have fun", say "eat", then you would not be able to use the も particle.

So to answer your question, yes they do mean to different things but when you break them down into their separate parts, they are quite simple and easy to understand.

To anyone else who sees this and knows more than me, please correct me and go easy on me as this is my first time answering a question. (If I am incorrect with anything)

Comment: You're first sentence is throwing me. でも is the て form of です?

Comment: Yes that's correct. Well the で is the  て form of です. も is the non logical inclusionary particle. https://www.japaneseprofessor.com/reference/grammar/conjugations-of-the-japanese-copula/

Comment: I see. So (Being straightforward) if I already introduced a context place and a action, but then I want to bring another place for the same action, then I can use でも ("Also did that in this other context"). Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: That is correct. It's the same if you wanted to use another particle too. If you wanted to say I went somewhere too. You would say 公園に行った。(I went to the park).   図書館にも行った。(I ALSO(も) went to the library). In these cases, I use に instead of で since it is a target/location marker and not some place where you do an activity. Which is で's purpose.

Comment: "DBJG" confirms that the で in でも is the て-form. I never knew that before. I'm not sure it helps my understanding though.

Comment: I look at it as も can mean "in addition too/as much as/even" and then 先生で is just the て-form of the copula. From may example, it can be broken down like standard A is B sentence. X is a teacher. 先生です. Switch the です to the て-form and you have the known subject,  先生, also makes mistakes. A teacher also makes mistakes. Even a teacher makes mistakes. Took me a little while to get used to that thinking but watching Cure Dolly videos on youtube drilled that type of thinking into my head lol.